# How to get saved values from the color module in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I'm trying to retrieve the hex values that I saved using the color module in a separate module I'm writing.  I'm unable to determine where these variables are stored or how to access them.
Any thoughts on where can get the hex values?  Are they stored in theme settings somewhere?

I attached my colors.inc file.

```
$info = [
  // Available colors and color labels used in theme.
  'fields' => [
    'primary' => t('Primary Color'),
    'secondary' => t('Secondary Color'),
    'text' => t('Text Color'),
    'background' => t('Background Color')
  ],
  // Pre-defined color schemes.
  'schemes' => [
     'default' => [
     'title' => t('Default'),
     'colors' => [
     'primary' => '#3f51b5',
     'secondary' => '#536dfe',
     'text' => '#3b3b3b',
     'background' => '#ffffff'
  ],
],
'red' => [
  'title' => t('Red'),
  'colors' => [
    'primary' => '#f44336',
    'secondary' => '#ffcdd2',
    'text' => '#600000',
    'background' => '#ffffff'
  ]
]
```

]
];

Answer (score 0):

After messing around and doing some research and I found that the variables were stored in the config table.  If you look at the config table you will see three fields: collection, name, and data.  The name will be color.theme.mytheme.

If you would like to see the values stored in this field run the following 
query:

SELECT 'name', convert(`data` using utf8)
FROM config
WHERE 'name' = 'color.theme.mytheme'

You can access the variables using the following command:
$config = \Drupal::config('color.theme.mytheme')->get('palette');

All values are store in an associative array with the key of palette.

I hope this helps someone.